# How to find text bounds for multilined text in P5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I need to create autosized text setting some box size:

```
text(textContent, textX, textY, textWidth, textHeight);
```

The problem is that the text is multilined because it can't place on one line. Ok, then I've tried to check textBounds - but it works only with one line of string. How to find bounds for text drawing in some box/rect (textWidth, textHeight)?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a little difficulty understanding your question. But if you wanted to create a box that encompassed all the text you could implement something like the following:

Lets assume we have our text stored to objects like this to make the logic easier to read:

```js
var text1 = {
  "str" : "This Is Line One",
  X1: 0, 
  Y1: 0, 
  X2: 300,
  Y2: 100, 
  size:30
}

var text2 = {
  "str" : "This Is Line 2",
  X1: 0,
  Y1: 30,
  X2: 300,
  Y2: 100,
  size:20
}
```

X1,Y1 is the upper left coordinate, and X2,Y2 is the lower right.

Now we have a data model to work with. We simply have to combine the bounds into a single rectangle.

**Remember:**
Rectangles are Declared like this:
`Rect(X,Y,Width,Height)`
Which is exactly the information `textBounds()` gives us!

Here is a quick and dirty example of the math:

```js
function draw() {
    textSize(this.text1.size);
    text(this.text1.str,this.text1.X1,this.text1.Y1,this.text1.X2,this.text1.Y2);

    textSize(this.text2.size);
    text(this.text2.str,this.text2.X1,this.text2.Y1,this.text2.X2,this.text2.Y2);

    //Get Text Bounds object for each text
    let text1box = this.font.textBounds(this.text1.str,this.text1.X1,this.text1.Y1,this.text1.size)
    let text2box = this.font.textBounds(this.text2.str,this.text2.X1,this.text2.Y1,this.text2.size)

    //Get the upper-left and lower-right coordinates of the bounding rectangle of all the text
    let bounds = {
        x1: min(text1box.X,text2box.X), //upper left x
        y1: min(text1box.Y,text2box.Y), //uper left y
        x2: max(text1box.x + text1box.w,text2box.x + text2box.w), //lower right x
        y2: max(text1box.y + text1box.y,text2box.y + text2box.h) //lower right y
    }

    //if you want padding:
    let padding = 2;

    rect(
        bounds.x1 - padding,
        bounds.y1 - padding,
        abs(bounds.x2, - bounds.x1) + padding, //Width of the bounding rectangle
        abs(bounds.y2 - bounds.y1) + padding //Height of the bounding rectangle
    )

}
```

To fully show the logic here is a [quick diagram I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBW4X.jpg)

The cool thing about this logic is that even if the text isn't lined up perfectly, it is still able to put a box around all the text.

Comment: The question is about finding the width/height of text() when calling it with a 5th argument, which makes the text wrap if its width is larger than that argument. Your answer only applies when _not_ providing that 5th argument.